# What's the equivalent of addslashes() in JSP / Servlets?

Tags: java, jsp

How to add slashes to a particular string in JSP?
I want to convert this PHP code `$subj = addslashes($_POST['txtsubjct']);` to JSP.

Comment: Note that writing raw Java code in JSP files is not the best practice. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files. A well designed JSP contains template/presentation logic only.

Answer (score 6):

`addslashes()` is not particularly needed:

If you want to protect from sql-injections, use [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String addSlashes(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
    s = s.replaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n");
    s = s.replaceAll("\\r", "\\\\r");
    s = s.replaceAll("\\00", "\\\\0");
    s = s.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");
    return s;
}
```