# Java (JSP) - Securing forms from 'bad inputs' and 'sql injection/poisoning'

Tags: sql, mysql, security, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

I know php has a function called "addslashes()" which is fairly effective, but does Java Server Pages (JSP) have an equivalent when dealing with forms?

Comment: Addslashes is actually a poor practice. `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be preferred or, better, just prepared statements (PDO). Note that writing raw Java code in a JSP file instead of a Java class is a poor practice as well ;) This is not a JSP problem/issue at all, but a Java/JDBC one.

Comment: Note: "fairly effective" is *not effective*.  `addslashes` is not in any way designed for security -- it's made for convenience.  It just helps noobs write bad PHP to generate semi-valid MySQL without taxing their brain cells too much.  It's not even close to secure, and only protects against the most basic of attacks -- and it's totally useless if you use a DBMS other than MySQL (unless that system allows backslashes to escape stuff, *which is not standard SQL*).

Comment: By the way, is this your classmate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065364/whats-the-equivalent-of-addslashes-in-jsp-servlets The very same question was asked before today, also with an `addslashes()` reference (while this kind question with a PHP reference has never been asked in years here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer on howto prevent SQL injection [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will update if I can't work it out/does not solve the issue.